# Install Nvidia GeForce 610M in Ubuntu 12.04LTS on ASUS K55VD

Tags: nvidia, asus

I bought an ASUS K55 VD with Inte i3, but cannot install Nvidia GeForce 610M in Ubuntu 12.04, Please guide me with step by step installation if u could please.

Thank You

Comment: Here it is [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is provided on the Ubuntu wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

Basic steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install  nvidia-kernel-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Finally change the driver on the Xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Configured Video Device"
Driver  "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Comment: @Braiam thanks for the tips. Edited for completeness.

Comment: If it is optimus graphics, installing nvidia forcefully will cause black screen.